# change to indirect "I shall be in Geneva on Monday" he said

Tags: direct-speech

change to indirect

> "I shall be in Geneva on Monday" he said.

I think it should be :

> he said that he would be in Geneva on Monday.

but the other options confusing me are:

A) He told that he would be in Geneva on Monday
B) He said that he shall be in Geneva on Monday

Comment: Hello Lawki,  You haven't asked a question.  What is difficult or confusing for you about this task? What have you tried already?  Why are you unsure of your answer?

Comment: I need to change the statement to the indirect form of speech

Comment: "I shall be in Geneva on Monday" he said

Comment: what is the correct indirect form

Comment: What is difficult or confusing for you about this task? What have you tried already? Why are you unsure of your answer? I don't want to just do your tasks for you.

Comment: I think it should be : he said that he would be in Geneva on Monday. but the other options confusing me are: A) He told that he would be in Geneva on Monday and B) He said that he shall be in Geneva on Monday

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct.

It would also be correct to change the verb to "told me".  But "He told that ..." is incorrect because "tell" requires a direct object like "me" or "him".

It is necessary to change the auxiliary verb from "shall" to "would" or "will".  Forming the future with "I shall" is a rather old fashioned and formal construction, but it is still correct in modern English. But you don't use "He shall"; it becomes "He will".  This is backshifted to "he would".